# What is the protein sequence taken as input in the Path-A prediction system

Tags: biochemistry, molecular-biology

Considering the Path-A based metabolic pathway prediction (http://nar.oxfordjournals.org/content/34/suppl_2/W714.short). It uses machine learning for pathway prediction. Suppose that the input was a protein sequence of a query organism. I do not understand what these protein sequences are? Are these the enzymes for the reactions?

> The basic algorithm has two inputs: a set of protein sequences from the query organism and a set of model pathways, one for each target pathway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not necessarily, they can be enzymes, but they include a lot more (the whole proteome).

> It takes a FASTA format file containing a set of query protein sequences from a single organism (**a partial or complete proteome**) and identifies those sequences that are likely to participate in any of its supported metabolic pathways
>
> Path-A predicts the pathways supported by arbitrary sets of proteins, using validated prediction techniques based on sequence alignment and machine learning.

Comment: The whole proteome as in the whole genetic sequence available?

Comment: @Rishika No, the [proteome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proteome).

Comment: so basically a proteome is the list of all the available proteins in an organism??